# Кнопка возврата назад

Tags: javascript

Итак. Есть у меня некая кнопка, которая используется для возврата назад. На случай, если человек зашел из поиска, другого сайта или новой вкладки, есть условие, отправляющее человека на главную страницу.

```
<a href="#" onclick="if (document.referrer.indexOf(window.location.host) !== -1) { history.go(-1); return false; } else { window.location.href = 'http://site.com'; }">Назад</a>
```

Однако, если страница была открыта в новом окне, ссылка перестает работать. Причины данной проблемы мне понятны, а вот можно ли это дело исправить/записать иначе? Чтоб при открытии ссылки в новом окне, при нажатии на эту кнопку так же отправляло на главную страницу?

Comment: а разве в новой вкладке `document.referrer.indexOf(window.location.host)` не равно -1? У вас тогда будет отправлять на главную. Или вы хотите чтобы вас по истории назад кинуло, которая в предыдущей вкладке была?

Comment: Если я вставляю ссылку в адресную строку, тогда да, не равно -1. Однако, если открыть ссылку в новом окне со страницы сайта или перейти по ссылке с target="_blank", тогда условие пытается вернуть нас по истории, а не главную, так как мы пришли с того же домена. Но, история для новой вкладки пуста и не происходит ничего при клике по данной кнопке.